# How to set ViewDragHelper sensitivity in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I use the SwipeBackActivity library in Kotlin. This library use ViewDragHelper when swipe activity. Thats some codes from this library;

```
   private final androidx.customview.widget.ViewDragHelper viewDragHelper;

private class ViewDragHelperCallBack extends androidx.customview.widget.ViewDragHelper.Callback {
    private ViewDragHelperCallBack() { /* compiled code */ }

    public boolean tryCaptureView(android.view.View child, int pointerId) { /* compiled code */ }

    public int getViewVerticalDragRange(android.view.View child) { /* compiled code */ }

    public int getViewHorizontalDragRange(android.view.View child) { /* compiled code */ }

    public int clampViewPositionVertical(android.view.View child, int top, int dy) { /* compiled code */ }

    public int clampViewPositionHorizontal(android.view.View child, int left, int dx) { /* compiled code */ }

    public void onViewDragStateChanged(int state) { /* compiled code */ }

    public void onViewPositionChanged(android.view.View changedView, int left, int top, int dx, int dy) { /* compiled code */ }

    public void onViewReleased(android.view.View releasedChild, float xvel, float yvel) { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

I want to set drag sensitivity. Someone wrote to this code on issues from github.

```
  viewDragHelper = ViewDragHelper.create(this, 0.1f, new ViewDragHelperCallBack());
```

but i cant find how to use this code. How can i define viewDragHelper in Kotlin? How can i set viewDragHelper in my project?